# Interchanging from exponential form to log form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, quadratics

[image]

Shouldn't the answer be

x = loge(everything else in the bracket)

why is the loge function divided by "k" ???

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: The log function should not be divided by $k$, so you're correct. It should be $x=\log\left(\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1-k^2}}{k}\right)$

Comment: One more typo in the book, I suppose. **You** are correct !

Comment: @confused I would ask that you delete this question, since your answer has been found... just a thought.